# I want to add and use function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to add a new function called `Age` to calculate age of a person using his birthday. So I worked with Resource Controller (RESTFUL). I don't know how to add this function and how to use it in views.

My function is :

```
public function getBirthday($date){
    return (int) ((time() - strtotime($date)) / 3600 / 24 / 365);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, add that method that would return person's age to your Person model class:

```
public function getAgeAttribute() {
  return (int) ((time() - strtotime($this->born_at) / 3600 / 24 / 365);
}
```

In your controller you'll need to pass a model object to the view:

```
public someControllerAction() {
  // get person from the database or create a new model
  $person = ...;

  return view('some.view')->with(['person' => $person]);
}
```

And then, in the Blade template you can display age by doing:

```
{{ $person->age }}
```

I'm just not sure why you mention resource controllers. Usually they do not have a related view that they use to render HTML, but instead they return plain data, that is later serialized (e.g. to JSON) and used as controller response.